# Searching missing number - simple example

Tags: c, algorithm

A little task on searching algorithm and complextiy in C. I just want to make sure im right.

I have n natural numbers from 1 to n+1 ordered from small to big, and i need to find the missing one.
For example: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 - ans: 4

The fastest and the simple answer is do one loop and check every number with the number that comes after it. And the complexity of that is O(n) in the worst case.

I thought maybe i missing something and i can find it with using Binary Search. Can anybody think on more efficient algorithm in that simple example? 
like O(log(n)) or something ?

Comment: Doesnt change worst case. Just average case gets better.

Comment: What is question 2 in the homework? Do I get credits on Monday

Comment: Are the numbers guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @EdHeal: marked your comment with a +1; I think, however, that user183297 is very aware of the fact that  when uses reads answers from StackOverflow that he must (legally binding!) cite the answer, including URL and author, in whatever document he generates.

Comment: Yes, they are unique/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a comparison-based algorithm, you can't beat `Lg(N)` comparisons in the worst case. This is simply because the answer is a number between `1` and `N` and it takes `Lg(N)` bits of information to represent such a number. (And a comparison gives you a single bit.)

Unless the distribution of the answers is very skewed, you can't do much better than `Lg(N)` on average.

Now I don't see how a non-comparison-based method could exploit the fact that the sequence is ordered, and do better than `O(N)`.

Comment: Marcus did write in his first strokes, how actually do it in better than O(n) and i did it, as he said.

Comment: @user183297: don't get your comment. You can very well do O(Lg(N)), but not better. O(N) is out of the race.

Answer (score 1):

There's obviously two answers:

If your problem is a purely theoretical problem, especially for large `n`, you'd do something like a binary search and check whether the middle between the two last boundaries is actually `(upper-lower)/2`.

However, if this is a practical question, for modern systems executing programs written in `C` and compiled by a modern, highly optimizing compiler for `n << 10000`, I'd assume that the linear search approach is much, much faster, simply because it can be vectorized so easily. In fact, modern CPUs have instructions to take e.g. each

1. 4 integers at once, subtract four other integers,
2. compare the result to [4 4 4 4]
3. increment the counter by 4,
4. load the next 4 integers,

and so on, which very neatly lends itself to the fact that CPUs and memory controllers prefetch linear memory, and thus, jumping around in logarithmically descending step sizes can have an enormous performance impact.

So: For large `n`, where linear search would be impractical, go for the binary search approach; for `n` where that is questionable, go for the linear search. If you not only have SIMD capabilities but also multiple cores, you will want to split your problem. If your problem is not actually **exactly 1** missing number, you might want to use a completely different approach ... The whole `O(n)` business is generally more of a benchmark usable purely for theoretical constructs, and unless the difference is immensely large, is rarely the sole reason to pick a specific algorithm in a real-world implementation.

Comment: Behavior of modern processor is such that you pay a high penalty for mis-predicted branches. Let us assume that the loop takes 4 cycles in case of correct prediction and 12 cycles otherwise. Let us assume that the binary search always mis-predicts, whereas linear search never does and finishes at N/2. So you compare 12.Lg(N) to 4.N/2/4 cycles. With these unfavourable hypothesis, the breakeven point is N=180.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: +1, can't really argue with these numbers, but you should consider the memory access problems, too: as long as your binary search jump width is larger than the available L2/L1 caches, the binary search algorithm will always lead to cache misses, and extensive "unnecessary" memory transfers. The penalty for a cache miss is roughly memory latency + transfer duration, so let's say it's 1000 cycles

Comment: Assuming a cache line size of M, the linear search will experience N/2/M cache misses, and the binary search Lg(N/M), as the first lookups will miss and a few last ones will hit. For M=128, the breakeven is N=512.

Comment: Marcus, although its not teoretical question, it is a question that required that little idea of "check whether the middle between the two last boundaries is actually (upper-lower)/2." I didnt think about it by myself.
Other part of your answer was just very interesting and high qualified. Thank you.